# JSP CONDITIONING listdata need display blank

Tags: jsp

I was new in jsp i got problem with conditioning in jsp the code below i mean to display the "otherwise" so list data displaying blank if list data more than 5. .my appreciate for any suggestion,

```
  <c:choose>
  <c:when test="${fn:length(actionBean.selectLampMaklumat)<=5}">
      <c:forEach items="${actionBean.selectLampMaklumat}" var="list">
          <tr>
           <td>${fn:escapeXml(list["BIL_NO"])}</td>
            <td>${fn:escapeXml(list["LEASES_NAME"])}</td>
            <td>${fn:escapeXml(list["LEASES_NO"])}</td>
            <td>${fn:escapeXml(list["LOT_NO"])}</td>
            <td>${fn:escapeXml(list["TEMPOH"])}</td>
            <td>${fn:escapeXml(list["LAND_AREA"])}&nbsp;${fn:escapeXml(list["LAND_UNIT"])}&nbsp;</td>
            <td>${fn:escapeXml(list["STATE_DESC"])} <br/>${fn:escapeXml(list["DISTRICT_DESC"])}<br/>${fn:escapeXml(list["CITY_NAME"])}</td>
          </tr>       
      </c:forEach>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise test="${fn:length(actionBean.selectLampMaklumat)>5}">
    <c:forEach items="${actionBean.selectLampMaklumat}" var="list">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<c:otherwise>
```

instead of

```
<c:otherwise test="${fn:length(actionBean.selectLampMaklumat)>5}">
```

Comment: thx alex, it's worked. .in addition i remove <c:forEach items="${actionBean.selectLampMaklumat}" var="list"> below . .coz i just need to display single blank list